# dispatch any action to redux it clears other part of state

Tags: reactjs, redux

When I try to call any other action in redux it is setting one part of the state to it's `initialState`.

My root reducer looks like this

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    credentials: combineReducers({
    cred,
    user,
    partner,
    merchant,
    bank,
    error,
    auth,
  }),
  preCredentials,
  theme,
});
```

the part of the state that is being cleared is `theme`.

[action dispatched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiJjk.png)

[state diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwIar.png)

Why this actions that have anything to do with theme reducer can change its state.

Theme reducer

```
function theme(state = { ...INITIAL_THEME }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOADING_THEME:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case SAVE_THEME:
      return {
        ...action.theme,
        error: {
          status: null,
          message: '',
        },
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case CLEAR_THEME:
      return INITIAL_THEME;
    default:
      return INITIAL_THEME;
  }
}
```

reducer of dispatched action

```
function preCredentials(state = { ...INITIAL_STATE }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SAVE_USERNAME:
      return { ...state,
        user: { ...state.user,
          fullName: action.fullName,
        },
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Because when you dispatch any action other than `LOADING_THEME,SAVE_THEME` it is clearing your state as it going to `default`, don't return `INITIAL_THEME` there, instead return `{...state}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function theme(state = { ...INITIAL_THEME }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOADING_THEME:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case SAVE_THEME:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.theme,
        error: {
          status: null,
          message: '',
        },
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case CLEAR_THEME:
      return INITIAL_THEME;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

return state instead of initial state